# Plotting Normal distribution in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to reproduce the following diagram in `TikZ` and `pgfplots`.
[image]

My MWE with regenerated graph is below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, 
  domain=0:6, 
  samples=100,
  axis lines*=left, 
  xlabel=$x$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, 
  width=12cm,
  xtick=\empty, 
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, 
  clip=false, 
  axis on top,
  grid = major
  ]

 \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(3, 1)};
\draw [yshift=1.4cm, latex-latex](axis cs:2, 0) -- node [fill=white] {$0.683$} (axis cs:4, 0);
\draw [yshift=0.3cm, latex-latex](axis cs:1, 0) -- node [fill=white] {$0.954$} (axis cs:5, 0);


\end{axis}

\node[below] at (1, 0)  {$\mu - 2\sigma$}; 
\node[below] at (2, 0)  {$\mu - \sigma$}; 
\node[below] at (3, 0)  {$\mu$}; 


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Issues**

1. Nodes are not properly placed.
2. How to remove y-axis?
3. How to draw vertical dotted line?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Related: [Plotting bell shaped curve in TikZ-PGF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43610/plotting-bell-shaped-curve-in-tikz-pgf)

Comment: You are better off using the tick options instead of adding the nodes manually. But if you want to add nodes manually, do it inside the `axis` environment and use the `axis cs:` coordinate system (as you did for the horizontal lines).

Comment: Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel for your helpful comment. You comment helped me to resolve one issue. Any idea about other two issues.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. As Qrrbrbirlbel said, move the nodes into the `axis` environment and use `(axis cs:...)`. Alternatively, you could move the nodes into the `axis` environment and set `disabledatascaling` in the `axis` options. That way, you can keep your coordinates (this won't work if you have very large values in your plot, though).
2. Use `hide y axis` to hide the y axis
3. For the lines, I would redefine the `gauss` function to take a third parameter (the `x` value). Then you can use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to calculate the value of the distribution at the required `x` coordinate, and use that to draw the lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, 
  domain=0:6, 
  samples=100,
  ymin=0,
  axis lines*=left, 
  xlabel=$x$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, 
  width=12cm,
  xtick=\empty, 
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, 
  clip=false, 
  axis on top,
  grid = major,
  hide y axis
  ]

 \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(x, 3, 1)};

\pgfmathsetmacro\valueA{gauss(1,3,1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueB{gauss(2,3,1)}
\draw [gray] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,\valueA)
    (axis cs:5,0) -- (axis cs:5,\valueA);
\draw [gray] (axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:2,\valueB)
    (axis cs:4,0) -- (axis cs:4,\valueB);
\draw [yshift=1.4cm, latex-latex](axis cs:2, 0) -- node [fill=white] {$0.683$} (axis cs:4, 0);
\draw [yshift=0.3cm, latex-latex](axis cs:1, 0) -- node [fill=white] {$0.954$} (axis cs:5, 0);

\node[below] at (axis cs:1, 0)  {$\mu - 2\sigma$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:2, 0)  {$\mu - \sigma$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:3, 0)  {$\mu$}; 
\end{axis}



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I want to produce the above plot in Beamer, how should I?