# Draw a normal distribution by Latex

Tags: plot

I would like to draw the following picture by Latex. Please help me a bit.

Kind Regards

[image]

Comment: May be help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100022/plotting-normal-distribution-in-pgfplots

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. There have been some similar questions before, see if any of these help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29359/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100022/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11368/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43610/