# How to draw this image using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

Beyond the solution to this particular diagram, can you explain **if there is** a general set of steps that you would follow to obtain this code?

**My guesses:** Would conversion to vector graphics give some guidelines?

Are there parts of the process that can be automated?
Etc.

**I tried:** Using Inkscape to convert to vector graphics and somehow get a bunch of coordinates that I could use as a guideline for the tikz code.

I got the following so far (I took some code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100030/574)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
\pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\begin{document}‎‎

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw=none](0,4)--node[anchor=center, above] (A) {Marginal
distribution of Brownian motion through time} (10,4) ;
\draw[->,very thick](0,0)--(0,4) node[anchor=south, above left,
rotate=90] {Spacial distribution};
\draw[->,very thick](0,0)-- node[anchor=north, below] {Time} (10,0);
\draw[dotted, domain=0:9,samples=35,thick] plot ({\x+0.5},
{sqrt(\x)/2+2});
\draw[dotted, domain=0:9,samples=35, thick, smooth, postaction=
{decorate, decoration={raise=-10pt, text along path,text 
align=center,text={Spread of Willow Tree}}}] plot ({\x+0.5},
{-sqrt(\x)/2+2});
\draw[very thin, domain=-0.5:2.5,samples=35] plot({gauss(\x, 1, 1)+1},
{\x+1}) node (B) {};
\draw[very thin, domain=-0.5:2.5,samples=35] plot({gauss(\x, 1, 0.5)+3},
{\x+1}) node (C) {};
\draw[very thin, domain=-0.5:2.5,samples=35] plot({gauss(\x, 1, 0.25)+5},
{\x+1}) node (D) {};
\draw[very thin, domain=-0.5:2.5,samples=35] plot({gauss(\x, 1, 0.2)+7},
{\x+1}) node (E) {};
\draw[->] (A) to (B);
\draw[->] (A) to (C);
\draw[->] (A) to (D);
\draw[->] (A) to (E);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What are you stuck on? You are basically asking for answers which not only draw your figure from scratch but also provide something like part of the `pgfplots` manual and cover image conversion, automation and unspecified further issues. Apart from anything else, that is much too broad. It cannot possibly be answered reasonably in this format. Also, what are you converting to vector and how? And why would that produce code? We don't know anything about the starting point so automation is essentially out of the question.

Comment: @cfr See the edit. Those questions were only my guesses. If they don't exist the answer doesn't need to add them.

Comment: Well, yes. You can use Inkscape to export TikZ code. That is an option. It is not very easy to edit the results as it won't be especially readable, but if you just need the code, it should work. Obviously, that will just draw it. It won't make it a plot, for example.

Comment: Thanks for posting some code. Could you please make it into a proper MWE?

Comment: @cfr No idea what is MWE. Market Energy Partners?

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy a MWE is a minimal working example; basically, a *complete* and minimal document showing either the problem or, as in your case, the current state of things. I completed your snippet into a proper MWE and added the resulting image. I hope it's OK.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted twice? What else do you need ?

Comment: @percusse I guess down-voters were too hasty and voted before the code was added. Down-voting so soon, specially when OP reacts, has always seemed to be a disgrace to me. At least my up-vote could neutralize one of the down-votes, and someone else's too.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina There was already code and it was only missing the preamble before the downvotes. I guess MWE stands for *My way of example* for them. The other vote is mine :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina There was no code when the original question was posted and none was added in the first edit. Plus the OP is not new to the site and so I think that makes a difference to what it is reasonable to expect. One of the down-votes was mine although I would not have added a second one. And I would almost certainly not have down-voted if the user was new to the site. But I also try to watch questions in this case so that I can react to changes. I think calling it a disgrace is a bit strong in this kind of case, myself, even if you disagree.

Comment: Could you clarify whether the code you've now got produces the image you want? If not, what do you want to look different? Right now, it seems that you have an answer to part of your question in the question because you've basically adapted the code to your needs already. Apologies for not explaining `MWE`. I had assumed, given that you'd obviously been asking/answering questions here for a while, that you would know what I meant. However, it seems nobody bothered to mention it before. This is unfortunate, because it makes it much easier to ask questions, solve problems, and get answers!

Comment: I also think that the method you used is a good one: find an example which does something somewhat like you want and try to adapt it to do just what you want. One thing this often does as well, is give you a command or keyword which you can search for in the documentation. With TikZ/PGF, this can really help in finding relevant bits of the rather bloated manuals.

Comment: @cfr Sorry if it sounded too harsh. However, I thought the code snippet was there, just missing the preamble, when the down-votes were cast, so that's what I called it a disgrace.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I don't know about the second one. But I down-voted when I first commented and there was no code at all. (Hence my 'what have you tried?' opening.) As I say, if it was a new user, I would not have down-voted at that point though I might well have commented. At the time, the question seemed to be a 'draw-this-for-me and explain-everything-you-do and explain-all-the-options' which I did not think a reasonable starting point coming from somebody familiar with the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should point you in the right direction...

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, line cap=round]
\draw [thick, ->] (0,-2) -- (0, 2)
  node [midway, sloped, above] {Spatial distribution};
\draw [thick, ->] (0,-2) -- (10,-2)
  node [midway, below] {Time};
\draw [thick, dotted] 
  plot [domain=-1.5:1.5, samples=50] ({(\x*2)^2+.5},\x)
  node [right, align=center] {Spread of \\ willow tree};
\foreach \t [count=\i] in {.1,0.5,1,1.5}
  \draw plot [domain=-3:3, samples=20, smooth]
    ({\i*2 + sqrt(0.5*\t*pi)*exp(-0.5*\t*pow(\x,2))}, \x/2)
    coordinate (distribution-\i);
\node [above] (label) at (5,2) 
  {Marginal distribution of Brownian motion through time};
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \draw [->, shorten >=1ex] (label) -- (distribution-\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. Didn't know you can do arithmetic with the names of the nodes. That will shorten the code in another diagram I am making.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a `pgfplots` approach:

[image: pgfplots]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
\pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[rotate=-90]

  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-0.5:2.5,
    xmin=-1, xmax=3,
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    xlabel=Spacial distribution, ylabel=Time,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    axis x line=bottom, axis y line=right,
    x axis line style = {very thick,stealth-},
    y axis line style = {very thick},
    height=\textwidth,
    width=.5\textwidth,
    clip=false]

    \addplot[mark=none, thick, dotted,
      postaction={decorate, decoration={raise=-10pt, text along path,
        text align={right, right indent=3.5cm},text={|\scriptsize|Spread of Willow Tree}}}]
      {((x-1)*2)^2+.5};

    \node [xshift=-1cm,rotate=90] (label) at (current bounding box.west) 
      {Marginal distribution of Brownian motion through time};

    \foreach \t/\i in {1/1, 0.5/3, 0.25/5, 0.2/7} {
      \addplot[samples=35,smooth] {gauss(x, 1, \t)+\i};          
      \edef\temp{
        \noexpand\coordinate (g-\i) at (axis cs:-0.5,\i);
        \noexpand\draw [->, shorten >=2ex] (label) -- (g-\i);}
      \temp
    }
  \end{axis}
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```