# gauss curves inside minipage and node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am really new to Latex and this has been my place of reference for the last weeks, so I wanted to ask you about a really weird thing that I have no clue how to solve...
Following this thread: [Plotting bell shaped curve in TikZ-PGF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43610/plotting-bell-shaped-curve-in-tikz-pgf) I am trying to include Normal distributions inside a minipage and node, but strangely, while the distributions outside the minipage look correct, inside it they sort of lose resolution... I am including a working example below. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\usepackage{tikz} %for transparency
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} %these distributions look flawless, but I don't want to picture them
    \begin{axis}[
    no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth,
    axis lines*=left,
    height=3cm, width=5cm,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    enlargelimits=upper, clip=false,
    grid=major]
    \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,0.5)};
    \addplot [thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=.985\textwidth,
        draw=green!70!black,
        line width=3pt,
        inner sep=7.5pt,
        rounded corners,
        outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {
            \small{\textcolor{green!70!black}{Tissue-specific expression\\}}
            \begin{tikzpicture} %these distributions look really distorted, and are the ones I want to include, inside the minipage
                \begin{axis}[
                no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth,
                axis lines*=left,
                height=3cm, width=5cm,
                xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
                enlargelimits=upper, clip=false,
                grid=major]
                \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,0.5)};
                \addplot [thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=.985\textwidth,
        draw=pink,
        line width=3pt,
        inner sep=7.5pt,
        rounded corners,
        outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {
        \small{\textcolor{pink}{Ubiquitous expression}}


        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Apart from the "resolution issue", I would like that more than one tikzpictures of distributions appear side by side in each minipage (3 per minipage)... any clue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not the `minipage`; the problem is nesting `tikzpicture`s, since this causes the settings to be inherited by the inner picture; in particular, your plot inherits the `rounded corner` option and this obviously distorts the image.

One way to prevent this, in this particular case, is to use the `sharp corners` for the inner picture, thus annhilating the outer `rounded corners` (thanks to **Jake** for this suggestion):

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\usepackage{tikz} %for transparency
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} %these distributions look flawless, but I don't want to picture them
    \begin{axis}[
    no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth,
    axis lines*=left,
    height=3cm, width=5cm,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    enlargelimits=upper, clip=false,
    grid=major]
    \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,0.5)};
    \addplot [thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=.985\textwidth,
        draw=green!70!black,
        line width=3pt,
        inner sep=7.5pt,
        rounded corners,
        outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {
            \small{\textcolor{green!70!black}{Tissue-specific expression\\}}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[sharp corners] %these distributions look really distorted, and are the ones I want to include, inside the minipage
                \begin{axis}[
                no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth,
                axis lines*=left,
                height=3cm, width=5cm,
                xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
                enlargelimits=upper, clip=false,
                grid=major]
                \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,0.5)};
                \addplot [thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=.985\textwidth,
        draw=pink,
        line width=3pt,
        inner sep=7.5pt,
        rounded corners,
        outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {
        \small{\textcolor{pink}{Ubiquitous expression}}


        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Another option, specially useful if there are many possible outer settings that shouldn't be inherited, is to previously save the plot in a box, and then use it:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\usepackage{tikz} %for transparency
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
            \begin{tikzpicture} %these distributions look really distorted, and are the ones I want to include, inside the minipage
                \begin{axis}[
                no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth,
                axis lines*=left,
                height=3cm, width=5cm,
                xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
                enlargelimits=upper, clip=false,
                grid=major]
                \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,0.5)};
                \addplot [thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} %these distributions look flawless, but I don't want to picture them
    \begin{axis}[
    no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth,
    axis lines*=left,
    height=3cm, width=5cm,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    enlargelimits=upper, clip=false,
    grid=major]
    \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,0.5)};
    \addplot [thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=.985\textwidth,
        draw=green!70!black,
        line width=3pt,
        inner sep=7.5pt,
        rounded corners,
        outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {
            {\small\textcolor{green!70!black}{Tissue-specific expression\\}}
            \usebox\mybox
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=.985\textwidth,
        draw=pink,
        line width=3pt,
        inner sep=7.5pt,
        rounded corners,
        outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {
        \small{\textcolor{pink}{Ubiquitous expression}}


        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Another (in my opinion better) solution, is to avoid nesting `tikzpicture`s altogether. You can produce the framed box differently using, for example, the [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package. An example with two plots in one `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage{tikz} %for transparency
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{mdframed}[
  innerlinewidth=3pt,
  innerlinecolor=green!70!black,
  roundcorner=5pt,
  middlelinewidth=0pt]
            \begin{tikzpicture} %these distributions look really distorted, and are the ones I want to include, inside the minipage
                \begin{axis}[
                no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth,
                axis lines*=left,
                height=3cm, width=5cm,
                xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
                enlargelimits=upper, clip=false,
                grid=major]
                \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,0.5)};
                \addplot [thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}\quad%
            \begin{tikzpicture} %these distributions look really distorted, and are the ones I want to include, inside the minipage
                \begin{axis}[
                no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth,
                axis lines*=left,
                height=3cm, width=5cm,
                xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
                enlargelimits=upper, clip=false,
                grid=major]
                \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,0.5)};
                \addplot [thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{mdframed}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

An example with two plots each one in its `mdframed` (side-by-side):

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage{tikz} %for transparency
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
}

\newenvironment{MyFrame}
  {\begin{mdframed}[
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
  innerlinewidth=3pt,
  innerlinecolor=green!70!black,
  roundcorner=5pt,
  middlelinewidth=0pt]
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{MyFrame}
\centering
            \begin{tikzpicture} %these distributions look really distorted, and are the ones I want to include, inside the minipage
                \begin{axis}[
                no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth,
                axis lines*=left,
                height=3cm, width=5cm,
                xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
                enlargelimits=upper, clip=false,
                grid=major]
                \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,0.5)};
                \addplot [thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}\quad%
\end{MyFrame}%
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{MyFrame}
\centering
            \begin{tikzpicture} %these distributions look really distorted, and are the ones I want to include, inside the minipage
                \begin{axis}[
                no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth,
                axis lines*=left,
                height=3cm, width=5cm,
                xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
                enlargelimits=upper, clip=false,
                grid=major]
                \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,0.5)};
                \addplot [thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{MyFrame}
\end{minipage}%
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aaah I see! your solution works like a charm, many thanks Gonzalo!

Comment: mdframed looks like a cleaner solution, just out of curiosity: how would I place two mdframes next to each other?

Comment: @user32674 please see my updated answer with an example having two side-by-side `mdframed` environments.

Comment: Many thanks Gonzalo, I'm implementing the solution with mdframed and works perfectly!! just one last little question... can I make the inside of the boxes transparent instead of white? Thanks!