# node on top of Gauss distribution

Tags: tikz-pgf

following this thread: [gauss curves inside minipage and node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120609/gauss-curves-inside-minipage-and-node) I have the following working example with a very specific problem. I want to include the sigmas above the double arrows, but without the tick line (remove the `\node` lines to see what I am talking about), is it possible? Besides, I do not really understand the coordinates specified in the node lines (why can't the `y` coordinate of the node be 0.2 instead of -0.1 as in the corresponding double arrow?). Many thanks in advance! See the code below:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\usepackage{tikz} %for transparency
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100,
            axis lines*=left, xlabel=\empty, ylabel=\empty,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
            height=3cm, width=4.25cm,
            xtick={3,6}, ytick=\empty,
            xticklabels={\tiny{$\mu$1},\tiny{$\mu$2}},
            enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top]
            \addplot [fill=pink, draw=none, domain=3.75:4.5] {gauss(3,0.5)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=pink, draw=none, domain=3:4.5] {gauss(6,1)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(3,0.5)};
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(2.25,0.2) (3.75,0.2)};
            \node[coordinate, pin={\tiny{$\sigma$1}}] at (axis cs: 3,-0.1){};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(4.5,0.12) (7.5,0.12)};
            \node[coordinate, pin={\tiny{$\sigma$2}}] at (axis cs: 6,-0.17){};
            \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `coordinate` node with a `pin` to place the `sigma` labels? Why don't you just use something like `\node at (axis cs: 6,0.12) [font=\tiny, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 2$};` to place the node directly where you want it?

Comment: Ops I see, yes that's what I should have done instead... many thanks Jake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like `\node at (axis cs: 6,0.12) [font=\tiny, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 2$};` to place the node directly where you want it.