# Plot cumulative normal distn in tikz

Tags: pgfplots

I tried to follow Jake from [Plotting bell shaped curve in TikZ-PGF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43610/plotting-bell-shaped-curve-in-tikz-pgf) with slight modification.

1) I just want the univariate normal cdf with red dash line at the cut-off, but some how my dash line seem awkward.

2) why the y axis label is in the middle of figure, not
 along with y-axis?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      no markers, domain=-4:4, samples=100,
      axis lines*=left, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
      every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
      every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
      height=4cm, width=7cm,
      xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}, ytick=\empty,
      enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
      grid = none
      ]
       \draw[dashed, red, thick] (axis description cs: 1.32,0) -- (axis description cs:1.32, 1);
      \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-4:1.32] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
      \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(0,1)};
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) your third axis options line `every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},` determines the y label position. If you comment it out, it gets better (but I do not know a good solution)
2) you need `axis cs` instead of `axis description cs`., and probably you should change the `addplot` order to plot the red dashed line as the last one.

Comment: For the y label: `every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.north west),anchor=south}`. I would suggest to use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}`. Starting with version 1.11 it would be possible to use: `\draw[dashed, red, thick] (1.32,0) -- (1.32, 1);`

Comment: Thanks Faekynn & esdd.
Your suggestions work. I really appreciate!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments