# Normal distribution plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I was wondering how I can replicate the normal distribution plot down below. I've tried doing it, but I can't seem to get it. Thanks.[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: You could find many examples of a normal distribution drawn, e.g. [Plotting bell shaped curve in TikZ-PGF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43610/123129), https://tikz.net/gaussians/