# How to Draw CDF of normal distribution in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does anyone know how to draw the Cumulative distribution function of Normal Distribution ([explained here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function)) in tikzpicture environment? Many thanks!

Comment: Not everybody needs to know the terms you have provided on TeX.SX though many users are working mathematicians. Please provide your own effort in terms the definitions and the things you have tried otherwise it's not easy for us to solve your problem.

Comment: Also related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31708/3235

Answer (score 21):

If you want to avoid using gnuplot to do the calculations, you can use an approximation of the normal CDF like the very nice and simple one given by [Bowling et al](http://www.jiem.org/index.php/jiem/article/download/60/27) (which [John D. Cook shows in his blog](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/04/29/simple-approximation-to-normal-distribution/)):

```
\tikzset{
    declare function={
        normcdf(\x,\m,\s)=1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((\x-\m)/\s)^3 - 1.5976*(\x-\m)/\s));
    }
}
```

The maximum error is given as 0.014%, which is more than sufficient for visualization purposes.

---

Here's a comparison of the gnuplot version and Bowling et al's approximation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\DeclareMathOperator{\CDF}{cdf}

\def\cdf(#1)(#2)(#3){0.5*(1+(erf((#1-#2)/(#3*sqrt(2)))))}%

\tikzset{
    declare function={
        normcdf(\x,\m,\s)=1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((\x-\m)/\s)^3 - 1.5976*(\x-\m)/\s));
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$\CDF(x)$,
  grid=major,
  legend entries={gnuplot, Bowling et al},
  legend pos=south east]
  \addplot[smooth, line width=3pt, orange!50] gnuplot{\cdf(x)(0)(2)};
  \addplot [smooth, black] {normcdf(x,0,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18):

One way to do so is to use `pgfplots` and interact with Gnuplot. In facts Gnuplot here is useful because of the `erf` function.

Here is a simple example to be compiled with `pdflatex -shell-escape`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\cdf(#1)(#2)(#3){0.5*(1+(erf((#1-#2)/(#3*sqrt(2)))))}%
% to be used: \cdf(x)(mean)(variance)

\DeclareMathOperator{\CDF}{cdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$\CDF(x)$,
  grid=major]
  \addplot[smooth,red] gnuplot{\cdf(x)(0)(1)};
  \addplot[smooth,blue]gnuplot{\cdf(x)(0.5)(1)};
  \addplot[smooth,green]gnuplot{\cdf(x)(1)(1)};
  \addplot[smooth,orange]gnuplot{\cdf(x)(2)(1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Notice that the function `\cdf` has been defined by means of `\def` to have `()` delimiters around arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Note that in newer versions of gnuplot there is the "norm" function that plots the standard normal cdf.

```
 \addplot [very thick] gnuplot{norm(x)};
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Another way is via `Asymptote`, which also has a  built-in `erf` function.
`cdfs.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{asydef}
import graph;
defaultpen(currentpen+fontsize(10pt));
typedef real realFunc(real);

struct cdfGraph{

  real xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;

  real cdfnormal(real x, real mu, real sigmaSquared){
    return 0.5*(1+erf((x-mu)/sqrt(2sigmaSquared)));
  }

  realFunc[] cdf;
  pen[] curvePen;
  string[] curveLegend;

  void add(real mu=0, real sigmaSquared=1,pen p=currentpen){
    cdf.push(new real(real x){return cdfnormal(x,mu,sigmaSquared);});
    curvePen.push(p);
    curveLegend.push("$\mu="+string(mu)+",\,"
      +"\sigma^2="+string(sigmaSquared)+"$");
  }

  void drawAxes(){
    xaxis(Label("$x$",0.5),BottomTop,xMin,xMax
      ,LeftTicks(Step=1,step=0.5,extend=true
         ,pTick=gray(0.3),ptick=gray(0.6)
      )
    );
    yaxis(Label("$\Phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(x)$",0.5)
      ,LeftRight,yMin,yMax
      ,RightTicks(Step=0.2,step=0.1,extend=true
         ,pTick=gray(0.3),ptick=gray(0.6)
         ,trailingzero
       )
    );
  }

  void draw(){
    for(int i=0;i<cdf.length;++i){
      draw(graph(cdf[i],xMin,xMax),curvePen[i],curveLegend[i]);
    }
    drawAxes();
    add(legend(linelength=20bp),(xMax,yMin),NW,UnFill);
  }

  void operator init(real xMin=-5, real xMax=5,real yMin=0, real yMax=1){
    this.xMin=xMin;
    this.xMax=xMax;
    this.yMin=yMin;
    this.yMax=yMax;
  }
}
\end{asydef}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
size(300,200,IgnoreAspect);

cdfGraph g=cdfGraph();

real w=1bp;

g.add(0,0.2,blue+w);
g.add(red+w);
g.add(0,5,rgb(0.784,0.541,0)+w);
g.add(-2,0.5,rgb(0.306,0.604,0.024)+w);

g.draw();
\end{asy}
\caption{Cumulative distribution function}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:

```
sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

and run `latexmk -pdf cdfs.tex`.

The solution consists of two parts:

- `asydef` environment (in the preamble), which defines the `struct` `cdfGraph`,
- and the `asy` picture environment that actually uses it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that may help.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4, yscale=4] 
\def\cumulative{\x,{1/(1 + exp((0-\x))}}
\def\betaA{\x,{1/(1 + (0.25*exp(0-\x))}}
\def\betaB{\x,{1/(1 + (0.5*exp(0-\x))}}
\def\betaC{\x,{1/(1 + (5*exp(0-\x))}}
\def\betaD{\x,{1/(1 + (15*exp(0-\x))}}
\draw[very thin,color=gray, step=0.25] (-6.1,-0.025) grid (5.9,1.025) ;
\draw[very thick, ->] (-6.1,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {Project Time} ; 
\draw[very thick, ->] (-6,-0.025) -- (-6,1.2) node[above] {\% Budget };
\draw[thick,color=red,domain=-6:6] plot (\cumulative);
\draw[thick,color=green,domain=-6:4] plot (\betaA) node[above left] {$\beta = 0.05$};
\draw[thick,color=blue,domain=-6:5] plot (\betaB) node[above] {$\beta = 0.25$};
\draw[thick,color=cyan,domain=-6:6] plot (\betaC) node[right] {$\beta = 5.00$};
\draw[thick,color=magenta,domain=-6:6] plot (\betaD) node[below right] {$\beta = 15.00$};
\node at (-6.4,0.25) {25\%};
\node at (-6.4,0.50) {50\%};
\node at (-6.4,0.75) {75\%};
\node at (-6.5,1.0) {100\%};

\node at (0,-.1){\textbf{Effect of Changing $\beta$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```