# how to draw CDF function for Poisson law tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, statistics

Does anyone know how to draw the Cumulative distribution function of Poisson Distribution (explained here) in tikzpicture environment? I tried with cumulative sums... without success.  Many thanks!

Comment: One way is to get data from the table and then plot.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60950.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot right-continuous function like the CDF of a Poisson distribution by using `pfgplots` with `jump mark left, mark=*`, e.g.
[image]

As minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}% for programming graphics 
\usepackage{pgfplots}% for scientific plots \begin{axis} etc
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.98\textwidth,
        legend pos=north west, 
        grid=major,
      ]
      \addplot[blue, ycomb, mark=*] table [x=k, y=pdf, col sep=comma]{poisson_distribution_data.csv};
      \addplot[red, jump mark left, mark=*] table [x=k, y=cdf, col sep=comma]{poisson_distribution_data.csv};
      \legend{
        Poisson PDF with \(\lambda = 4\)\\
        Poisson CDF \\
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Where the data is computed by `python .\poisson_distribution.py` given as

```
import numpy as np
import csv

lambda_0 = 4
with open('poisson_distribution_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["k", "pdf", "cdf", lambda_0])
    s = 0
    kmax = 12
    for k in range(kmax):
        pdf = np.exp(-lambda_0) * ((lambda_0 ** k) / np.math.factorial(k))
        s += pdf
        writer.writerow([k, pdf, s])
```