# Marginal function and total function curves using the pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I draw this diagram following a [conversation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515670/probability-density-function-and-cumulative-distribution-function-for-normal-dis)  though I could not understand the `declare function` part and so took the same values to get closer to what I needed. However, I need the following amendments:

1. Moving the x-axis label from below to right of the axis, and removing the ticks and values -3, -2 etc.
2. Changing the diagram aspect ratio: reducing the height to almost 0.75 of the current height and increasing the width to 1.5 of the current width.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath, amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,fillbetween}
\DeclareMathOperator{\CDF}{cdf}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PDF}{pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
    normcdf(\x,\m,\s)=1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((\x-\m)/\s)^3 - 1.5976*(\x-\m)/\s));
    gauss(\x,\u,\v)=1/(\v*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\u)^2)/(2*\v^2));
    }]
    
    \begin{groupplot}
    [group style={group size=1 by 2},
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=0,
    domain=-3:3, xlabel=Time, axis lines=left]
    
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=Marginal Response, ytick=\empty, ymax=1]
    \addplot[smooth, black,thick, xtick=\empty] {gauss(x,0,1)};
    \draw [dashed](0,0)--(0,1);
    \draw [dashed](3,0)--(3,1);
    
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=Cumulative Response, ytick=\empty, ymax=1]
    \addplot[smooth, black,thick] {normcdf(x,0,1)};
    \draw [dashed](0,0)--(0,2);
    \draw [dashed](3,0)--(3,2);
    
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the width and height with the `width` and `height` keys. You were already using `ytick=\empty` to remove the y ticks, another `xtick=\empty` will remove the x ticks. And you can move the x label via

```
xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:1,0)},anchor=north east},
```

To have lines that go across the group plots, you can define symbolic coordinates that you use in the ambient `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath, amsmath}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% loaded by tikz
%\usepackage{tikz}% loaded by pgfplots 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,fillbetween}
\DeclareMathOperator{\CDF}{cdf}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PDF}{pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
    normcdf(\x,\m,\s)=1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((\x-\m)/\s)^3 - 1.5976*(\x-\m)/\s));
    gauss(\x,\u,\v)=1/(\v*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\u)^2)/(2*\v^2));
    }]
    
    \begin{groupplot}
    [group style={group size=1 by 2},
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=0,width=12cm,height=6cm,
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ymax=1,
    xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:1,0)},anchor=north east},
    domain=-3:3, xlabel=Time, axis lines=left]
    
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=Marginal Response]
    \addplot[smooth, black,thick, xtick=\empty] {gauss(x,0,1)};
    \path (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) coordinate (t1)
     (3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) coordinate (t2);
    
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=Cumulative Response]
    \addplot[smooth, black,thick] {normcdf(x,0,1)};
    \path (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) coordinate (b1)
     (3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) coordinate (b2);
    
    \end{groupplot}
    \draw[dashed] (b1) -- (t1);
    \draw[dashed] (b2) -- (t2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
And how can we extend the two vertical dashed lines from lower panel to the upper panel?

Comment: @AmosMachado I added them.