# Finding LaTeX source code for a common template

Tags: templates

I often see documents formatted like the following:

[image]

and

[image]

with sleek boxes and a nice outline at the top of each slide.

I like this style; would anyone happen to know where I can find the source?

Comment: Have you asked the authors? BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: No I have not. I'll email them.

Comment: They look like `beamer` documents- try `texdoc beamer` to look through the manual

Comment: @cmhughes that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the first one is the "Copenhagen" theme and the second "Singapore" in Beamer.
See: http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
for a gallery of themes.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31708/draw-a-bivariate-normal-distribution-in-tikz