# Concentric ellipses with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am hoping to recreate the image you see below in tex (the original here was done in Word). After snooping around for some time, I see that this should be done using the Tikz package. However, I don't have any experience with this package and am trying to prepare this for a lecture relatively soon (poor planning on my part). Can anyone help recreate this image? [image]

Thank you! Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: You might also like [Gaussian ellipsoids using tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115340/2552), [Draw a bivariate normal distribution in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31708/2552), and [How can two bivariate normal distributions be plotted in one plot?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198741/how-can-two-bivariate-normal-distributions-be-plotted-in-one-plot)

Answer (score 6):

The shadow stuff is a Word habit. I recommend you to reconsider that habit because it doesn't mean anything plus it gives the idea that these things are floating which is obviously not the case.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0) (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\draw[rotate around={45:(-0.5,0.5)},double=red,ultra thin,double distance=0.5pt] (-0.5,0.5) ellipse (0.2 and 0.5) ellipse (0.4 and 0.8);
\draw[rotate around={45:(0.5,-0.5)},double=blue,ultra thin,double distance=0.5pt] (0.5,-0.5) ellipse (0.2 and 0.5) ellipse (0.4 and 0.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]