# How can I map a 3D plot into the planes using pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

After answering a question in pgfplots, asking to plot a function; I thought about how I can map the 3D function into the planes. Something like the plots in [this page](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/contour-and-surface/) but I could not reach any solution.

Here are my functions and their output. I want to show the left plot in the xy plane of the 3d plot; or map the function on xz and yz planes.

[image]

```
% pdflatex
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \pgfmathdeclarefunction{F}{3}{\pgfmathparse{#1* exp(#2*#3)}}
\begin{axis}
        [
        smooth, grid=both,minor tick num=1,
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        tick align=inside,
        samples=1000,
        samples y=0,
        ]

        \addplot [solid, thick, data cs=polarrad, domain=0:10*pi] {F(5,-0.1,x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
~
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \pgfmathdeclarefunction{F}{3}{\pgfmathparse{#1* exp(#2*#3)}}
\begin{axis}
        [smooth, grid=both,minor tick num=1,
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,
        samples=1000,
        samples y=0,
        ]

        \addplot3+
        [solid, thick, black,
        mark=none,
        thick,
        domain=0:10*pi,
        ]
        ({F(5,-0.1,x)*cos(deg(x))},{F(5,-0.1,x)*sin(deg(x))},{F(5,-0.1,x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addplot3 [...] ({F(5,-0.1,x)*cos(deg(x))},{F(5,-0.1,x)*sin(deg(x))},{0});` will plot the function in the `xy` plane. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Jake That is exactly what I want. I want to show the function in the xy, xz, yz and 3D plot in just one plot output. I mean, show those 2d functions in the walls of the 3d plot.

Comment: You can take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31715/2552 for something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Jake for [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209278/how-can-i-map-a-3d-plot-into-the-planes-using-pgfplots#comment488939_209278), I plotted what I wanted. The plot seems a liitle ugly because it is crowded with four plots; however it is really nice to show mapped functions besides to their 3d shape plot. Also, the important point in plotting such graph was that the user should take care at which coordinate the side walls of the 2d plot is located. At the bellow plot, at z=0, the xy plane exists; at y=4, the xz plane exists and at x=-4 the yz plane exists.

[image]

```
% pdflatex
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \pgfmathdeclarefunction{F}{3}{\pgfmathparse{#1* exp(#2*#3)}}
\begin{axis}
        [smooth, grid=both,minor tick num=1,
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,
        samples=1000,
        samples y=0,
        domain y=0:6
        ]

        \addplot3+
        [dashed, black,thick,
        mark=none,
        thick,
        domain=0:25*pi,
        ]
        ({F(5,-0.1,x)*cos(deg(x))},{F(5,-0.1,x)*sin(deg(x))},{F(5,-0.1,x)});

        \addplot3 [domain=0:25*pi,samples=500, samples y=0, black!50, smooth] ({F(5,-0.1,x)*cos(deg(x))},{F(5,-0.1,x)*sin(deg(x))},{0});
        \addplot3 [domain=0:25*pi,samples=500, samples y=0, red!50, smooth] ({F(5,-0.1,x)*cos(deg(x))},{4},{F(5,-0.1,x)});
        \addplot3 [domain=0:25*pi,samples=500, samples y=0, blue!50, smooth] ({-4},{F(5,-0.1,x)*sin(deg(x))},{F(5,-0.1,x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```