# Plotting a Bivariate Normal Distribution in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have been trying to make a 3D plot of a certain bivariate normal distribution but that is far from ideal at the moment. The code I have been using is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
width=6in,
height=4in,
title=Bivariate Normal Distribution,
axis lines=left,
grid=both,
]
\addplot3[samples=50,surf,faceted color=blue]
{1/(2 *pi* sqrt(1-0.9^2))* exp(-(x^2+y^2-2*0.9*x*y)/(2*(1-0.9^2))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces this

[image]

This is is not what I would like though and me messing with the different graphical parameters of `\addplot3` does not lead to a more pleasant result for the eyes. Ideally, the surface I would like to produce is something like this

[image]

I really don't mind the shape, I can change it without any problems, it's the graphics I am having trouble with. Could you please tell me which parameters I need to change to get something like the picture above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference between the image of the 3rd party tool and `pgfplots` is that you have a considerably more involved example for `pgfplots`: the sampling density is way too low to draw a *rotated* asymmetric distribution in cartesian coordinates.

Options include:

1. do not use a rotated distribution if it does not matter anyway. Solutions how to do it are shown in all detail in [Draw a bivariate normal distribution in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31708/draw-a-bivariate-normal-distribution-in-tikz), in this case it is a duplicate.
2. maybe polar coordinates are better suited (I did not try it)
3. increase the sampling density

Here is what comes out of approach (3):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=6in,
height=4in,
title=Bivariate Normal Distribution,
axis lines=left,
grid=both,
]
\addplot3[samples=150,surf,shader=interp]
{1/(2 *pi* sqrt(1-0.9^2))* exp(-(x^2+y^2-2*0.9*x*y)/(2*(1-0.9^2)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I made some obvious and some non-obvious changes to your code and I would like to discuss them here:

1. `\centering` inside of a `tikzpicture` has no effect.
2. I added `compat=1.12` and compiled the picture with `lualatex`. This is *much* faster than any older `compat` level or `pdflatex`.
3. I fixed a syntax error in your math expression: the last '`)`' is missing (causing the `lua backend` to bail out and fall back to the slow TeX implementation which lives with the syntax error).
4. I used `shader=interp` since `samples=150` results in too many grid lines when used with `faceted`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It's the surface of the density that I would like to imitate somehow, that is why the other answer does not cover it. I do not mind the color, there is the other answer for that.

Comment: OK. Do you need more input in order to fulfil your task? Otherwise you can accept the answer.

Comment: I would like to create the kind of surface of the picture I have posted, aside from the color. Is that possible?

Comment: Since my image already is kind of that surface, I would like to know what you have in mind. Grid lines? Tick labels? black mesh on top of some colored surface? A precise parameterization of a gaussian with the parameters of the image?

Comment: Hello Christian, it's ok I have figured it out. Thank you for your help.