# Error by creating normal distribution in PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Hello I wanna create a Normal distributed figure.
with sigma = 10 and mu =185;

I have the following code based on [Bi-variate Normal distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31708/draw-a-bivariate-normal-distribution-in-tikz)

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={mu=185;}, %
        declare function={sigma=10;}, %
        declare function={normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));}] %
        \begin{axis}[
        width=15cm,
        enlargelimits=false,
        grid=major,
        domain=-1:4,
        y domain=-1:4,
        samples=201,
        xlabel=$x_1$,
        ylabel=$P$,
        ]
        \addplot [domain=150:220,samples=201, samples y=0, thick, smooth] (x,4,{normal(mu,sigma)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The thing is that i get every time the following error.

> Paragraph ended before \pgfflt@readlowlevelfloat was complete 
> \begin{axis} on input line 480 ended by \end{document}. \end{document} 
> Missing \endgroup inserted \end{document}

What does I wrong? The stupid thing is that when I copy the original it works fine and mine less big version doesn't work…

I hope somebody can help me

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create a three-dimensional plot, like in the answer you linked to, or just a two-dimensional one (like your use of `\addplot` instead of `\addplot3` suggests)?

Comment: Maybe [Plotting bell shaped curve in TikZ-PGF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43610/plotting-bell-shaped-curve-in-tikz-pgf) might be a better starting point for your purposes.

Comment: I want create a 2 dimensional as i did. The link was mine example.   
Both methods have to come to the same result isn't it?
What is than the difference??   
But still i don't understand why my latex won't run and gives errors...

Comment: Use `\addplot [domain=150:220,samples=201,thick, smooth] {normal(mu,sigma)};`

Comment: @Jan-Bert Coordinate `(x,4,{normal(mu,sigma)})` is 3D coordinate...

Comment: There is an error in the declaration of normal function: it is necessary to change `(2*\s*sqrt(pi))` for `(\s*sqrt(2*pi))`

Comment: Thanks for the Tips it works.  
another thing. I try to get arrows under my figure like showed in [Plotting bell shaped curve in TikZ-PGF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43610/plotting-bell-shaped-curve-in-tikz-pgf).  
I can't figure out why `\draw [yshift=-0.6cm, latex-latex](axis cs:-10,0) -- node [fill=white] {$x_1$} (axis cs:-15,0);` doesn't work.
I don't get any error. But it doesn't show anything eighter…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: @Jan-Bert Don't use comments to ask another question.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I do not like close because answered in comment. IMHO adding an answer should always be preferred and closing would prevent everyone from doing this.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, in general I agree, but for me it is ok, when it either was "a simple" solution like here, where it was a "typo" of OP, or (also like here) it is an "old" question.