# Draw a grid of bivariate normal distributions in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, 3d

This question was answered in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31708/draw-a-bivariate-normal-distribution-in-tikz), but I would like a small adaptation of it.

I would like to take the top solution of the above post. Instead of a single bi-variate distribution, I would like to have a grid of such distributions. The grid should be rectangular with controllable positions for each source.

I would then like to adapt this resulting image to remove all of the axes to leave behind just the surface distribution.

The grid I would like should be something like that [here](https://ibb.co/kWvbYQ). But the position of each circle should be a 2D Gaussian.

### Desired output

Something like this, with and without projections on the axes.

[image]

### The distribution

Each source on the grid should have the following distribution:

$$f(x, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_x \sigma_y}\exp[-\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2} + -\frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2}]$$.

with $\sigma_x = \sigma_y$ and varying values for $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ for the different sources. Note that this distribution has a diagonal form for the covariance matrix with elements $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ on the diagonal.

Comment: And, where is your problem? What have you done so far?

Comment: @Huang_d, getting a second distribution using the `\addplot3 [surf]` plot at a different location. It does not produce 2 seperate distributions.

Comment: One big problem (if I understand correctly) is, you won't be able to draw several intersecting surfaces using PgfPlots, as it won't be able to decide correctly which is in the front / in the back.

Comment: @marsupilam, I see. Is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: You could draw each surface only on the relevant domain and put them side by side. Do you have a model picture of what you would like, or more details of which gaussians you want and what grid you are thinking of ?

Comment: @marsupilam see updated question for a link to a grid picture.

Comment: I would recommend generating the data outside of LaTeX, using Matlab or Python, for instance, and only using PGFPlots do generate the plot. As marsupilam said, it would be helpful to see a sketch of the desired result, or at least a more detailed description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if I'll ever understand the thing with loops in pgfplots.

### The output

[image]

### The (simplistic) code

@Jake is right in pointing out this is a lot of computations for pgfplots, and you may be well-advised to pre-compute the functions *via* an external tool

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    declare function=
    {
      gaussian(\x)= exp(-.5*\x^2);
      gaussianDouble(\x,\y)= gaussian(\x)*gaussian(\y);
    }
]
\begin{axis}
  \foreach\i in {0,4,...,12}
  {
    \foreach\j in {0,4,...,12}
    {
      \addplot3[surf, samples=20, domain=-2:2, y domain=-2:2]({x+\i},{y-\j},{gaussianDouble(x,y)});
    }
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

### In Scilab

Not an answer, but is this what you want ?

If so, may I edit your question to include the pic in it ?

#### The output

[image]

#### The (Scilab) code

```
function z=normal(x,y)
  norm = x.^2 + y.^2
  z = exp(-.5*norm)
endfunction
clf()
x=linspace(-3,3,30)
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x)
for i=0:2:10
  for j=0:2:10
    surf(X+i,Y+j,normal(X,Y))
  end
end
f=gcf()
f.color_map = autumncolormap(32);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I would like thanks - with and without a distribution shown projected on the xz and yz axes (much like the original post in question). I would still prefer it in TikZ, but you are most welcome to edit the question to illustrate the desired output.

Comment: @Sid Alright, then, you would need to tell us the `x` and `y` step of the lattice you are using, and the covariance matrix for the Gaussian distributions. Otherwise, no computation can be done...

Comment: Added the form of the distribution to the question.

Comment: It's true that it takes 20-30 seconds in `pgfplots`, but remember that you only have to compile it once.  You can then subsequently include it using `\includegraphics.`

Comment: @JPi Sure, but I chose a rather low `samples` value and few bumps... It's unlikely you can get stellar graphics using this simple approach.

Comment: Right, though mostly because of tex memory limitations...